# How to apply a function to every two columns with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I would like to create a custom function that will apply a calculation to transform each 2 columns into a column vector:
`numpy.sum(matrix[index here]**2, axis = 1)`

Is there a numpythonic way I can slide over every two columns? Thanks.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i76822156/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

#### Splitting

Split the matrix horizontally, apply function to each new array, and stack the resulting vectors together:

```
npairs = data.shape[1] // 2
func = lambda x: (x*x).sum(1, keepdims=True)
answer = np.hstack([func(arr) for arr in np.hsplit(data, npairs)])
```

#### Reshaping

On reshaping, we iterate over the horizontal axis with two new indexes, where the last one is 2 in order to divide columns into pairs. Then we apply a required function along the last axis:

```
arr = data.reshape(data.shape[0], -1, 2)
answer = (arr*arr).sum(-1)
```

Notes:

- `data.reshape(x, -1, y)` means that the first and last dimensions are set to `x` and `y`, and the middle value is calculated automatically
- `data.sum(-1)` means calculate the sum along the last axis